# Video overlay for Direct X for Windows

Tags: windows, directx, overlay

Is it possible to have a video overlay on top of a Direct X.
For example I want to have a video playing while playing a game.

Steam and Fraps both have custom UI overlays for Direct X applications. Is there anyway to have this for video ?

Comment: If this is a programming question, it's better to transfer it to stackoverflow.

Comment: Unless there is an existing application that can do this

Comment: DirectX overlay is on top of everything on your screen, so just create your overlay and play the video. but, most graphics card support only one overlay surface, if other application has created one, then you cannot create any more. but I think games will not use overlay.